# JMeter parallel running two threads not working with selenium

Tags: multithreading, selenium, jmeter, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have a test in which I use a thread group with 2 users (numbers of threads) and ramp up period of 1 second. Although 2 browsers start and load the website (as expected) one of them stops and one continues to do the work. Any help appreciated. I am using Firefox 43 with Selenium 2.53.1 and JMeter 3.3

Here is the configuration
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Most probably your test implementation is not [thread-safe](https://www.journaldev.com/1061/thread-safety-in-java) and JMeter threads are running into a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) when 2 threads are trying to access the same Selenium Session.
2. Selenium WebDriver itself [is not thread-safe](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#q-is-webdriver-thread-safe) so make sure that each JMeter Thread is using a separate dedicated WebDriver instance.
3. Check out *jmeter.log* file - in majority of cases it contains enough information to guess the root cause of JMeter test malfunction
4. Are you aware of [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) plugin which provides Selenium integration with JMeter? You can consider switching to it or at least using its [source code](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/tree/master/plugins/webdriver) as a reference

Comment: 1) If I am not explicitly using threads in my code I don;t see how would that be possible

2) This could be it, but that's weird because I don;t know what would be the role of jmeter then, if I had multiple drivers in my code, I can run it from eclipse then/

3) Well, nothing suspicious :(

4) I'll definitely look at that

Answer (score 0):

Add a Synchronizing Timer should help.
(Take a look of the article 
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer)
But I only found one request in your image that I don't really understand about the problem you're facing.

Comment: In image you can see that there are 2 Threads (users) defined, so it should run the same test twice, at the same time. I managed to get to that point, (so that 2 browsers are open) but only one works

Comment: I don't think your setting make any limit that will make two threads run at the same time.When you set the ramp up period to 1 second, it only ensures that two threads will be start in 1 second but not starting the request at the same time. Therefore, a Synchronizing Timer should help to solve this issue.

Comment: I don't care if they start at the same time or one is sooner and one is later (1 second later) - what I need is to keep them running parallel. When I start first test and set ramp-up period to 1 second, my first test stops working immediately, only the second test continues

Comment: Will it cause by the code behind like accessing the database, therefore, when one of them using the resource, the other one will be stop?